# PHP Sessions Not Working--Trying Again with Simplified Example

Tags: php, session

Since our web server was rebooted, PHP sessions are no longer working. Several people gave me helpful ideas, but none of them worked. I made a VERY simplified example that I'm pretty sure should work, but it does not work. If someone can explain why I will be very grateful. I've spent a whole day on this so far.

My understanding is that $_SESSION is supposed to be "super global" meaning it's available anywhere.

For clarity, I made two stripped down, rewritten pages where the code STILL doesn't work, i.e. print "Hello World".

If someone could tell me what is wrong with THIS I would greatly appreciate it!

----------- WEB PAGE ONE.PHP -----------------

```
<?PHP session_start(); ?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page One</title>
</head><body>
<?PHP
     $_SESSION['testvalue'] = "Hello World";
?>
<p><a href="pagetwo.php">Click here</a> to see page two</p>
</body></html>
```

----------- WEB PAGE TWO.PHP -----------------

```
<?PHP session_start(); ?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Two</title>
</head><body>
<?PHP echo $_SESSION['testvalue']; ?>
<br>
</body></html>
```

I run web page one and click the link to go to page two, and instead of a page showing "Hello World" I get

Notice: Undefined index: testvalue in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\two.php

I checked C:\PROGRAMDATA\PHP\SESSIONS and there is a file in there called

**sess_905m06314ibdubru8ko0aqj4d1**

Which contains the following

**testvalue|s:11:"hello world";**

This file was created when I ran **one.php**, indicating that the app has permission to write the session information

Sorry if I seem dense but I'm just not understanding why this isn't working and have spent the better part of a day trying to figure it out.

Thank you.

Comment: Precisions: are the two pages on the same webserver? Do you access them using a different domain? Are the cookie settings in apache correct? A session is transmitted to the client using cookies, and it is imperative for the domain settings on them to be configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to store sessions into another directory (you do this by editing php.ini) :

```
session.save_path = "C:\php_session_test"
```

The reason why is because ProgramData is a "special folder" on Windows 7, there is some file system redirections (like `C:\Windows\System32`, `C:\Windows\Sysnative`...).

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the session isn't being propogated to page 2. Do you have cookies disabled?
https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php shows how you can pass the SID in the URL. Try that and see if you can access the session then. Check the cookies in your browser and do a phpinfo() to see the session id if necessary. If it's different on page 2 then that is your problem.